# How to specify values on y axis of a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I need to generate a graph using matplotlib like the one in the attached picture. So far I tried it like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
y = np.array([20,21,22,23])
my_xticks = ['John','Arnold','Mavis','Matt']
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

How can I specify a different number of values on the y axis different from the number of values on the x axis? And maybe specify them as an interval with 0.005 difference instead of a list?

[image: desired image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
y = np.array([0.650, 0.660, 0.675, 0.685])
my_xticks = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
plt.yticks(np.arange(y.min(), y.max(), 0.005))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.grid(axis='y', linestyle='-')
plt.show()
```

Something like this should work.

Answer (score 0):

The values on y-axis are called y tick labels (ticks are the short lines on an axis). As @Martini showed, it can be set using the state machine. There's also the the object-oriented approach, which I think is more transparent.

This approach is one where you can explicitly create an Axes object and call the appropriate methods (which is done under the hood with `plt.xticks()` anyway).

*Option #1.* For example, to set yticks, there's the dedicated `ax.set_yticks()` method.

```py
x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
y = np.array([0.650, 0.660, 0.675, 0.685])
my_xticks = ['John','Arnold','Mavis','Matt']


fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='white')           # create figure and axes objects
ax.plot(x, y)                                       # make plot
ax.set_xticks(x)                                    # set x tick positions
ax.set_xticklabels(my_xticks)                       # set the corresponding x tick labels
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(y.min(), y.max(), 0.005))   # set y tick positions
ax.grid(axis='y');                                  # draw grid
```

*Option #2.* The Axes object also define `set()` method that can be used to set multiple properties such as xticks, yticks, ylabel etc.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='white')
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set(xticks=x, xticklabels=my_xticks, yticks=np.arange(y.min(), y.max(), 0.005), xlabel='x axis', ylabel='y axis');
ax.grid(axis='y');
```

*Option #3.* Each Axes defines Axis objects as well (YAxis and XAxis), each of which define a `set()` method that can be used to set properties on that axis.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='white')
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.xaxis.set(ticks=x, ticklabels=my_xticks, label_text='x axis')
ax.yaxis.set(ticks=np.arange(y.min(), y.max(), 0.005), label_text='y axis')
ax.yaxis.grid();
```

[image: result]