# Scatter plots in python from a csv file with string in x-axis

Tags: python, string, matplotlib

I have a csv file with strings as x-axis. Now i have to make a scatter plot using matplotlib and pandas.
But its showing error "scatter plots require number in x axis"

I tried reading the file as a variable df and scatter plotted it.But it isnt able is to read strings. Its a huge file and i cant define string variables as 
x = ["x1","x2",...etc]

*There are also multiple values for the same x axis id.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("scatter2")
ax = plt.gca()
df.plot(kind='scatter',x='Spectral Type',y='Hα EW',ax=ax)
```

The error message: 
...ValueError: scatter requires x column to be numeric

Comment: Matplotlib should be able to plot this like `ax.scatter(x='Spectral Type',y='Hα EW', data=df)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your x values have to be a normal range list (e.g. something like `list(range(len(x)))`) and then you just set your `ticks` to the desired value (something like `plt.xticks(x_range_values, x_str_values)`).

Have a look at [Python Matplotlib - how to specify values on y axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393802/python-matplotlib-how-to-specify-values-on-y-axis) for a bit more information